# How to set subtab label of a component opened from another component using only PageReference and not workspace API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference, lightningnavigation

When i open a subtab from my main component, the label is loading...
I only need to use pageReference type and as per the requirement, i cannot use worksapce API.
Need help.
My code:

```
ViewCallHistory : function(component,event,helper)
{
var pageReference = {

                                "type": "standard__component",
                                "attributes": {
                                    "componentName": "c__CallOutcomeHistory",
                                    "actionName": "CallOutcomeHistory"
                                },    
                                "state": {
                                    "c__projTargetId" : component.get('v.ProjectTargetId'),
                                }
                            }
                            navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
```

the actionName is not a parameter for standard__component!
any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Hi Ankur, `standard__component` doesn't support the `actionName`. But you can use the state to pass another param and handle it in the component.

Comment: hi Miguel, yes, i can pass another param, but how can i set it as a label for the subtab that is opened.. .currently it says ...loading...

Comment: There's a method called `setTabTitle` that could work. Take a look at the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_settabtitle.htm).